# AngularJS remove `x-csrf-token` in $http.get

Tags: angularjs, http

I'd like to make a call to a 3rd party API using `$http`. However, it's including a `x-csrf-token` in the request which I believe is throwing off the request.

```
var req = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Token <token>'
    }
}
return $http(req)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to load `URL`: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
>   access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

When I look at the request, it's being sent as `OPTIONS`. Is the issue that I'm sending the x-csrf-token in the header and I need to remove it? Or am I missing something else? How can I successfully make this `GET` request?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your request seems to be correct. However, it appears that the API you try to call doesn't accept Cross Origin Resource Sharing.

This is not an AngularJS issue, but a server one.

If the API is yours, add a CORS policy.

If the API is something like Google, Spotify or whatever, don't forget to register your URL as accepted domain.